# How to get reference to first element of Array

Tags: c#

I'm having a converter routine that converts/casts from on array type into another.
Originally the method looked like this:

```
static void Convert<TTo>(Array source, TTo[] target);
```

But there is a need to go with Span in the future, so the new method should look like this

```
static void Convert<TTo>(Array source, in Span<TTo> target)
```

Currently I call the conversions in my internal routines

```
public double GetSumOfAbsoluteDifferences(Array imageData1, Add imageData2)
{
  // Convert to float
  float[] id1 = new float[imageData1.Length];
  float[] id2 = new float[imageData2.Length];

  DataConversion.Convert<float>(imageData1, id1);
  DataConversion.Convert<float>(imageData2, id2);

  double sum=0;
  for (int i=0; i<imageData1.Length; i++)
  {
    sum += Math.Abs(id1[i] - id2[i]);
  }

  return sum;
}
```

The old method was able to convert any dimension of the array into a one dimensional array which is OK.
Originally I had to do a lot of unsafe code to make the method as generic as possible, at least for struct or unmanaged types. Since I have no typed version of `Array` I needed to do a GCHandle.Alloc and pin the array for the time of the cast. My current implementation looks like this (for brevity only one converter is shown):

```
public unsafe static class DataConversion
{
    public delegate void Converter(void* source, void* target, int n);
    
    readonly static Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, Converter>> Converters = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Type, Converter>>();
    
    static DataConversion()
    {
        Converters.Add(typeof(int), new Dictionary<Type, Converter>()
            {
                [typeof(float)] = Convert_Int_Float
            }
        );
    }
    
    private unsafe static void Convert<TTo>(Array source, in Span<TTo> target)
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(source, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    
        var sourceType = source.GetType().GetElementType();
    
        Converter converter = Converters[sourceType][typeof(TTo)];
        converter(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer(), Unsafe.AsPointer(ref target[0]), source.Length);
    
        handle.Free();
    }
    
    private static unsafe void Convert_Int_Float(void* source, void* target, int n)
    {
        var from = new ReadOnlySpan<int>(source, n);
        var to = new Span<float>(target, n);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            to[i] = (float)from[i];
    }
}
```

My question is though if it is possible to do this without any unsafe code? The problem I have is that I cannot event make the converter methods (here: `Convert_Int_Float`) generic since then they wouldn't fit into the dictionary. My only option was to put it into the most generic version which was/is `void *`.

So my question is if there is a somewhat better approach?

Comment: You can use structures for the data which make it easier to convert.  Using Marshal method and binary serialization can also help.

Comment: [`MemoryMarshal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @aepot: Thats what I tried, but couldn't find the appropriate method. The best I found was CreateFromPinnedArray but then I have to pin and cast. Which I want to avoid.

Comment: Without understanding what do you really want to achieve and maybe some example of the data it's difficult to say something useful here. Where's the data came from? You may update the question with the additional info.

Comment: I have added some example, but I'm not sure if this will help. I want to convert from one type into another that's the only thing. The question is though that I can have generic arrays T[], Array or ReadOnlySpan<T>, Span<T>, Memory<R>, ReadOnlyMemory<T>, as input and I need some way of handle them all in the fastest possible way.